# plot3d of an image in SCILAB

Tags: matlab, scilab

I'm try to plot a gray image using `plot3d` in Scilab, here is my code:

```
clear;
clc;
direc='C:\Users\engine\Documents\EYE';
cd(direc)
stacksize('max');
fileName = '50.jpg';
rgb= ReadImage(fileName);
img = RGB2Gray(rgb);
Histogram =  CreateHistogram(img);
figure(1); plot( 0:255,Histogram);

plot3d(1:length(img(:,1)),1:length(img(1,:)),img(:,:));
imshow(img);
```

When I run this code, I get this error message :

```
!--error 246 
Function not defined for given argument type(s),

  check arguments or define function %i_plot3d for overloading.
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: You have at least one error in this line: `plot3d(1:lennth(img(:,1)),1:length(img(1,:)),img(:,:));`. You have written `lennth`, and not `length`.

Comment: I've correct it, I still get the same error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I should convert the gray image to double values, the plot works fine then :

```
clear;
clc;
direc='C:\Users\engine\Documents\EYE';
cd(direc)
stacksize('max');
fileName = '50.jpg';
rgb= ReadImage(fileName);
img = RGB2Gray(rgb);
img2 = im2double(img);
img2 =img2*250;
plot3d(1:1024,1:1280,img2(:,:));
```